# Why can't the Solana validator code base be built with its own tooling?

Tags: cargo

I am at commit 67d3beeb35e62b8a04b1e511a5917a205db622df.  Recent rustup has installed rustc 1.67.0 (fc594f156 2023-01-24), and cargo 1.67.0 (8ecd4f20a 2023-01-10).  However, the version of rustc and cargo doesn't seem to matter as these errors occurred on other older versions too.

`./cargo build` produces this error:

```
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
  --> /home/bji/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/enum-iterator-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:66:12
   |
66 | #![feature(array_from_fn)]
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This error is saying you need to use nightly Rust: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136717/errore0554-feature-may-not-be-used-on-the-stable-release-channel-couldnt

You can do this with `rustup default nightly` and change back with `rustup default stable`